# Find max value across multiple spreadsheets and return contents of adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have six spreadsheets (named, Book 1, Book 2, Book 3 etc), all with identical tables, that track a book's Amazon ranking each day.

Date. Rank. Genre.

On a summary page, I'd like to return the details of the highest ranking book for each day.. eg:

Date. Highest Ranking Book

I have figured out how to return the value of the highest rank with MAX('Sheet1:Sheet6'!C3, but I do not know how to then return the name of the spreadsheet (contained in A3 on each sheet) or the Genre, which is adjacent in D3.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Have you looked at index(match(max())), use your max() to feed the match and the index will go to the other column - sorry I’m on a phone so can’t build an example yet, however there are examples on stack overflow...

Comment: Yes, I have looked into that. And, tbh, it did my head in. I could not understand how the index function worked across the multiple sheets.

Comment: Write one for each sheet, compare... then pull out the final result....

Comment: If I wanted to take the long way, I could copy it all through to a datasheet at the back and pull it from there. I'm after a more elegant solution in a single formula. If possible. Everything is set up to work with 'Sheet1:Sheet2'! referencing.

Comment: Since your data sounds similar, why don’t you have it all in one sheet? This would make comparison calculations easier...

Comment: Each sheet is also filled up with graphs. And, the aesthetic of it. I shall think on that if this can't be done.

Comment: So perhaps one master sheet for data, sheets with graphs and the summary sheet of comparisons ...

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike, it would be much easier to have a data sheet, with all ratings of all day (with a date field), a summary page with the date and the rank (using MAXIFS), and perhaps another one with charts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my formulas:

Summary Sheet

A2: `=INDEX(INDIRECT(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"}&"!b:b"),B2),{"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"})&"!a:a"),MATCH(Summary!B2,INDIRECT(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"}&"!b:b"),B2),{"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"})&"!b:b")))`

B2:`=MAX(Book1:Book6!B2)`

C2:`=VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT(LOOKUP(1,0/COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"}&"!b:b"),B2),{"Book1";"Book2";"Book3";"Book4";"Book5";"Book6"})&"!b:c"),2,0)`

My Sample:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]